# How to update tensorflow properly on kaggle?

Tags: tensorflow, kaggle

I want to update tf to 2.7.0, after update the tf through the command:

[image]

i check whether the upgrade is successful:
[image]

it turns out no available GPUs were found:
[image]

Why is that?
And how can I correctly upgrade the version of tensorflow?

Answer (score 0):

First, update the Tensorflow version in Kaggle kernel by

```
!pip install -U tensorflow==2.3.1
```

then, update GPU version in GPU cluster :

```
print("update GPU server TensorFlow version...")

!pip install cloud-gpu-client

import tensorflow as tf 

from cloud_gpu_client import Client

print(tf.__version__)

Client().configure_tpu_version(tf.__version__, restart_type='ifNeeded')
```

press CTL+SHIFT+P and select restart kernel

Kaggle itself has guides explaining the usage of these libraries on their kernel.

However, consider this sufficient for now.